# Reactjs setState() with a dynamic key name not working

Tags: reactjs, state

Here the code https://codesandbox.io/s/yqxr2z02pv

I am using this code so i dont need setState one by one onUpdate

```
  onUpdate = (event) => {
    const { target: { name, value } } = event
    console.log(value);
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
  }
```

But the component not show the value when input value changed.

Any simple example can made this working?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of duplicating the state in the `Parent` and the `Child` you can keep the state just in the `Parent` component and pass them down as props. You could also put the `name` prop on your `inputs` and use the `onUpdate` prop directly to pass along the event.

**Example**

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      firstName: "firstName",
      lastName: "lastName"
    };
  }

  onUpdate = event => {
    const {
      target: { name, value }
    } = event;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  render() {
    const { firstName, lastName } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Parent</h2>
        Value in Parent Component State firstName: {firstName}
        <br />
        Value in Parent Component State lastName: {lastName}
        <br />
        <Child
          onUpdate={this.onUpdate}
          firstName={firstName}
          lastName={lastName}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { firstName, lastName, onUpdate } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Child</h4>
        first Name
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          name="firstName"
          onChange={onUpdate}
          value={firstName}
        />
        <br />
        last Name
        <input
          type="text"
          name="lastName"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={onUpdate}
          value={lastName}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making an object first and adding the dynamic key to that like so

```
onUpdate = (event) => {
    const { target: { name, value } } = event
    console.log(value);

    const newData = {};
    newData[name] = value;
    this.setState(newData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit your code.  you can try.
https://codesandbox.io/s/m37wlryy78?fontsize=14

Child.js

```
import React from "react";

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: ""
    };
  }

  update = e => {
    this.props.onUpdate(e);
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Child</h4>
        first Name
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.update}
          value={this.state.firstName}
          name={"firstName"}
        />
        <br />
        last Name
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.update}
          value={this.state.lastName}
          name={"lastName"}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you explain in your answer what have you changed and what was wrong?